# My <input> box won't display single quotes

Tags: php, html

If it has a single quote in it, any string that I try to enter into my HTML input box is truncated in the input box once it is submitted.  Its POST value comes thru unchanged, but the string shows as truncated in the input box, whether I use htmlspecialchars() or not. A noobie question, no doubt, but I've tried hard to figure it out and run out of ideas. Thanks for any help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body><title> Self-inserting input_box_SO.php </title>
    <?php
    //  POST form initiation.
    ECHO "<form action='input_box_SO.php' method='post'>"; 

    // GET POSTed value and escape it for HTML use
    $Caption_htmlspecialchars=$_POST['Caption_htmlspecialchars'];
    $Caption_htmlspecialchars=htmlspecialchars($Caption_htmlspecialchars);
    ECHO "The echo of the variable <em> \$Caption_htmlspecialchars </em> looks like this:<br>";
    ECHO "<b> $Caption_htmlspecialchars </b><br>";
    ECHO "But in the input box, \$Caption_htmlspecialchars is truncated by a single quote: <br>";
    // ETA: Bad old line that caused the problem, now commented:
    // ECHO "<input type='text' name='Caption_htmlspecialchars' size=100 value='$Caption_htmlspecialchars' maxlength = 100 required /><br><br>"; 
    // ETA: Newly added line that fixes the problem:
echo '<input type="text" name="Caption_htmlspecialchars" size=100 value="'.$Caption_htmlspecialchars.'" maxlength = 100 required /><br><br>';
    // SUBMIT button.  Submits back to the same page: input_box.php
    echo "<b><input type='Submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></b></br></br>";
    ?>
    </body></html>
```

[image]

Here is what Inspect Elements > Elements shows for the input element:

input_box_SO.php 
The echo of the variable  *$Caption_htmlspecialchars*  looks like this:
 **test with special chars. & " < > and a single quote ('), which causes truncation in the input box.**  
But in the input box, $Caption_htmlspecialchars is truncated by a single quote: 
 and a single quote (" ),="" which="" causes="" truncation="" in="" the="" input="" box.="" '="" maxlength="100" required="">

With the Source looking like this:  `value='test with special chars. &amp; &quot; &lt; &gt; and a single quote ('), which causes truncation in the input box. '`

Comment: Could you set a demonstration on jsfiddle or codepen for this?

Comment: I don't know but no truncation happen at my end. can you create some example link to demonstrate your problem.I am unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Use html code &#39 . Can you just show what is there on inspect element in input element.

Comment: you have maxlength =100 . Remove and check

Comment: Sorry Difster and Alive to Die, I'm not up on jsfiddle yet, or able to set up links.  I've edited the question above, Sagar to try to respond to your request for what Inspect Element was showing.  I'll try doing that escaping for myself with &#39.  I tried getting rid of the maxlength=100 to no avail, Alive to Die.  Thanks, all, for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your sequence of single quotes nad double quotes to display string. change your `echo <input` as below

```
echo '<input type="text" name="Caption_htmlspecialchars" size=100 value="'.$Caption_htmlspecialchars.'" maxlength = 100 required /><br><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `addslashes` and do it like

`$Caption_htmlspecialchars = addslashes($Caption_htmlspecialchars);`

Comment: That did not put the rest of the text back into the HTML input box. But thank you for your entry. The answer from @B.Desai works perfectly, one has to swap all the double quotes for singles and single quotes for doubles in your echo line.